# CSS dynamic Id target

Tags: html, css

I am developing an app without javascript. The concept is no-js.

So I have comment section for reply.

this is the button.

```
<a href='#reply1'>
   Reply button
</a>
```

Reply form.

```
<form id='reply1'>
  <p>
    A reply form
  </p>
</form>
```

and this is my style.

```
<style>
  #reply1 {
    display: none;
  }

  #reply1:target {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

Currently it's working very well,  when I click on reply button, the reply form shows up.

But in my case , the id will be dynamic. Every form will have different id and for every form there will be a button with the same id as of form.

I heard that it can implemented with css wilcard or someother way. I don't know how to do that. Can anyone help me to get it done?

Comment: you can use a class and make use of it to style the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

If you want to apply your style to multiple elements, then the **class selector** is an option.

```css
.reply-form {
  display: none;
}

.reply-form:target {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<a href='#reply1'>Reply buttion1</a><br/>
<a href='#reply2'>Reply buttion2</a><br/>
<a href='#reply3'>Reply buttion3</a><br/>


<form id='reply1' class="reply-form">
  <p>A reply form1</p>
</form>

<form id='reply2' class="reply-form">
  <p>A reply form2</p>
</form>

<form id='reply3' class="reply-form">
  <p>A reply form3</p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `class` attribute.

```
<style>
  .reply {
    display: none;
  }

  .reply:target {
    display: block;
  }
</style>
```

Now, irrespective of whatever `id` you use, till you mention `class="reply"` the styles will be added

```
<form id='reply1' class="reply">
  <p>
    A reply form
  </p>
</form>

<form id='reply2' class="reply">
  <p>
    A reply form
  </p>
</form>
```

In the above example, reply css will be added to both `id="reply1"` and `id="reply2"`

Comment: You don't need to. Guy has asked over 100 questions, accepted answers to over half of them. It's generally bad manners to ask for answer acceptance unless the user is really new.